# Word give to a person who likes to give their opinions on random topics

Tags: single-word-requests

So I'm starting a blogging website where I give my opinion on random things I see in my daily life: homeless people, best restaurants, libraries, street performers. Just random things I see and I want to express my opinion on. Is there a word that describes me? In no way are my thoughts correct; they're just my options on the subject.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Are you an expert, or just somebody offering an opinion, like every other blogger?

Answer (score 1):

You could be called a **pundit**.  [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/pundit)

> a person who knows a lot about a particular subject(s); someone who gives opinions in a way that sounds intelligent or wise: